# Where is the 'selected to active' bake option in new version?

Tags: baking, id-mask

Where is the 'selected to active' bake option in new 2.8 version?
There is 'bake from multires' now, but options are only normals and displacement, and I need to bake color

Comment: It should be a little bit down, right after the influence section. could you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just posting this so I can post this pic. This is taken from blender 2.83 in Cycles. If you're setup doesn't look like this, there's likely something wrong with your version of blender.

[image: BakeSettings]

Comment: I dont have this.
Im starting to think i have beta version or something, have been noticing strange things in blender lately

Comment: thank you for answer

Comment: No problem. Are you using 2.83?

Comment: mine version is 2.83.2

Comment: just downloaded it from site, and it has the option. Maybe steam version broken or something? gonna try verify integrity